# Ugly WPF text rendering - can't disable hardware acceleration on Vista

Tags: wpf, windows-vista, 3d, hardware-acceleration

I'm experimenting problems with text rendering in WPF (third party applications and mine too). Labels and other text don't display correctly, look a little blurred and are rendered with some random colored pixels around.

I'm working on a low end <strike>crap</strike> machine (SiS Mirage 3 graphics) with Vista SP1, .NET 3.5 SP1 and graphics driver updated.

Another poor souls having [similar problems](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=483373) were answered to try disabling hardware acceleration for WPF using Microsoft instructions to change the registry key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DisableHWAcceleration`

The ultimate issue to me is: I can't find "Avalon.Graphics" in the registry at all. It's not there. Someone have a clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just creating it? It's specifically mentioned in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx), so I'd imagine it's correct (or rather I'd *hope* it was correct :-))

Comment: Someone tried it (third post at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ab182577-d78f-4f0a-a03d-8de451010118/) apparently without success. But I'll try this too

Comment: Another option is to use the advanced display properties in Windows to crank the acceleration down a few notches. I had to do that with an early build of Win7 on my netbook.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting SnapToPixels?  This did wonders to a lot of our views.  I know exactly what you are talking about, though.

Try:

```
<Window ..
     SnapToPixels="True">
...
</Window>
```

And see if that makes a difference.

I *have* noticed a bit of blurring when applying TextEffects, so if you are doing that you might want to look at turning those down or off and see what you get.

Comment: This has worked for me for both text and graphics. It got my upvote.

Comment: I'll try it and give you a feedback. Thanks.

Comment: I tried SnapToDevicePixels but it didn't work in my case, actually.